# How can I prove $ \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}x_{i}2^{i}\leq\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}2^{i}=2^{k}-1<2^{k} $

Tags: proof-writing, summation

How can I prove this inequality property? Assumption: The values of $x_i$ can either be 0 or 1

Comment: Any assumption on the $x_i$?

Comment: The value of $x_i$ can be 1 or 0

Comment: $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}2^{i}\neq2^{k-1}$

Comment: and you just need $x_i\leq 1$, since $x_i=0$ or $1$, so the 1st inequality is trivial

Comment: @freak_warrior How does the RHS arise from the LHS?

Answer (score 3):

There is a mistake in your problem: in fact $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 2^i=2^k-1$.

As for solution note that $x_i 2^i\leq 2^i$, so this inequlity remains for the sum.

Comment: I found this in a book, it says it makes use of the property to solve another sum.

Comment: Fixed the property

Comment: How does this inequality remain for the sum?

Comment: $a_1<b_1$ and $a_2<b_2$ implies $a_1+a_2<b_1+b_2$. The same idea works for any amount of summands

Comment: Alright, And how does the RHS arise from the LHS?

Comment: which rhs and lhs?

Comment: The $2^k -1 < 2^k$ is the RHS

Comment: Use geometric series formula $1+q+q^2+\ldots+q^{k-1}=\frac{q^k-1}{q-1}$

Comment: That should give us $2^k -1$ in the RHS of $2^k -1 < 2^k$ also right? Then how $2^k$ only?

Comment: take $q=2$, then you get $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 2^i=\frac{2^k-1}{2-1}=2^k-1<2^k$.